# Setting up IntelliJ 2017 to work with Gradle 4.2 and the latest Play Framework 2.6

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to setup IntelliJ 2017.2 to work with my Play 2.6 application using Gradle 4.2.1.

I also have the Scala plugin for IntelliJ installed.

After hours of sifting through various blogs and guides I've created a build.gradle file that looks like this which should have done the trick:

```
plugins {
    id 'play'
    id 'idea'
}

model {
    components {
        play {
            platform play: '2.6.6', scala: '2.11'
            injectedRoutesGenerator = true
        } 
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += project.file('app')
        testSourceDirs += project.file('test')

        project.file("${project.buildDir}/src/play/binary").listFiles().each {
            if (it.name.endsWith('ScalaSources')) {
                sourceDirs += it
                generatedSourceDirs += it
            }
        }

        outputDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/playBinary/classes")
        testOutputDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/playBinary/testClasses")

        scopes.COMPILE = [plus: [configurations.play], minus: []]
        scopes.RUNTIME = [plus: [configurations.playRun], minus:[configurations.play]]
        scopes.TEST = [plus: [configurations.playTest], minus: [configurations.playRun]]

        sourceDirs += project.file('conf')
        testSourceDirs += project.file('test/resources')
    }
}

dependencies {
    // dependencies...
}
```

The main issue I'm facing is that IntelliJ can't find all of my sources correctly.

If I try to manually add things in the project settings (say for the "app" directory), my changes get reset with a Gradle refresh.

I have also tried playing around with the Gradle configurations like "Create separate module per source set" but it hasn't really helped much.

I know this isn't a typical setup since most people use SBT with Play, but unfortunately, we're stuck with this for the time being since Gradle is the standard at work. Has anyone had any luck with this setup of IntelliJ 2017, Gradle 4.2, and Play 2.6?

Answer (score 0):

I found that Intellij 2017 does not really support the Gradle play plugin. I'm running IDEA 2017 3.5 and Gradle 4.6, and a simple import of a Gradle project from build.gradle will not work. IDEA becomes little more than Notepad when working with source files.

What I think is happening, is that IDEA is hard-coded to look specifically for configurations and source sets of the Java plugin. Your scopes configuration may do the same thing, but first, I added two configurations:

```
// IDEA will not use the dependencies unless it finds these particular configurations.

configurations.create(JavaPlugin.COMPILE_CLASSPATH_CONFIGURATION_NAME, configuration -> {
    configuration.extendsFrom(configurations.findByName(PlayPluginConfigurations.COMPILE_CONFIGURATION));
    configuration.setTransitive(true);
});

configurations.create(JavaPlugin.TEST_COMPILE_CLASSPATH_CONFIGURATION_NAME, configuration -> {
    configuration.extendsFrom(configurations.findByName(PlayPluginConfigurations.TEST_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION));
    configuration.setTransitive(true);
});
```

That allows IDEA to recognize the gradle dependencies, but they won't show up in the IDE unless they are tied to module sources of the IDEA project structure, so I then add two source sets -- which are there for the sole purpose of triggering IDEA to recognize dependencies and not for IDEA to use them in building anything. (I apply the 'java-base' plugin, and use the sourceSets of the JavaPluginConvention object.)

```
    sourceSets.create("main", sourceSet -> {
        sourceSet.getJava().setSrcDirs(Collections.singletonList("app"));
        sourceSet.getJava().setOutputDir(fileResolver.resolve("build/playBinary/classes"));
        sourceSet.getResources().setSrcDirs(Collections.singletonList("conf"));
        sourceSet.getResources().setOutputDir(fileResolver.resolve("build/playBinary/resources"));
    });

    sourceSets.create("test", sourceSet -> {
        sourceSet.getJava().setSrcDirs(Collections.singletonList("test"));
        sourceSet.getJava().setOutputDir(fileResolver.resolve("build/playBinary/classes"));
        sourceSet.getResources().setSrcDirs(Collections.singletonList("test/resources"));
        sourceSet.getResources().setOutputDir(fileResolver.resolve("build/playBinary/resources"));
    });
```

I'm still missing a few details. If there is anybody out there who can add details, I would be happy to share my plugin which the above comes from. I'm not using the 'idea' plugin -- I just apply the 'play' plugin alone, and apply the above fixes, and import the project as a Gradle project. The gradle tasks work fine in the IDE, and dependencies show correctly and all the goodness of the IDE as far as navigating the source with clicks on things, is brought back to life.